# Module vs vector space chart

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, modules

Does anyone have a good comparison chart for modules vs vector spaces?

For instance, rank of submodules is bound above by rank of a free module over a PID, but this property is not generally true. I'm wondering if there is any chart in circulation that lists vector space properties with counter examples in modules and conditions needed/sufficient to get the same property.